# Wordpress / PHP Error

Tags: php, wordpress

Im receiving this error in WordPress from a widget. Any suggestions?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /nfs/c02/h01/mnt/39510/domains/tc325.com/html/wp-content/themes/chefry/woocommerce/product-searchform.php on line 29

Here's the code

```
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( ''Search', 'submit button', 'chefry''); ?>"/></label>
```

Comment: This `''` opens and closes the encapsulation.

Comment: Is this an off-the-shelf plugin? If so, that's a real shame.  This: `<input type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( ''Search', 'submit button', 'chefry''); ?>"/></label>` should be this: `<input type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'chefry'); ?>"/></label>`

Comment: try : `esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'chefry');`

Comment: Clearly this question isn't a duplicate of what it's linked to. And much less an "exact duplicate"

Comment: Sorry thats giving the same error code